# Best approach for Firestore rules for following tree

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**My problem is as follows:** *I am relatively new to firebase :)*

**Edit**

August provided this great firestore setup for my original problem. Now the question is how to use the firestore rules to allow only read access for users that are within that certain project/company. Here is August's answer from before:

```
Companies (collection)
   CompanyUID (document)
       companyData
       Projects (collection)
           ProjectUID (document)
               projectData
               projectUsers
       Employees (collection)
           employeeList (data or document)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Companies (collection)
   CompanyUID (document)
       companyData
       Projects (collection)
           ProjectUID (document)
               projectData
               projectUsers
       Employees (collection)
           employeeList (data or document)
```

It's pretty simple with Firebase, go for it and keep it simple! I like to use unique ID's as document/collection names often, then I keep the actual project name within the document.

I also like to think in terms of security of what data is private and what can be public, so I desing the structure are simple security rules. For example I will have two collections: Users, and Profiles. Under Users I will keep all of a users private data, and under profiles I will keep all of a users public data. Feel free to ask me any questions I've made quite a few databases with Firebase.

Comment: Thanks! Any advice on how to use firestore rules for this? A little stuck on that part.